# EWS ExchangeService.GetAttachments returning 401 Unauthorized using OAuthCredentials

Tags: c#, oauth, exchangewebservices, office-js

I'm currently developing an angular add in for Outlook and part of the functionality for this add in requires my remote service obtaining the attachments of an email from Outlook.

I've been following [this Docs link here in regards to my functionality.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item)

So currently I'm able to get the attachmentToken via Office.js in my angular code and pass up that along with the ExchangeWebServiceURL to my remote service:

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync((result) => {
  if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    this.outlookServiceRequest.attachmentToken = result.value;
  }
});
```

However once I get here:

```
                ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService();
            exchangeService.Url = new Uri(attachmentsRequest.exchangeWebServiceUrl);
            exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(attachmentsRequest.attachmentToken);

            var attachmentIds = new List<string>();
            foreach (OutlookAttachmentDetails attachment in attachmentsRequest.AttachmentArray)
            {
                attachmentIds.Add(attachment.id);
            }

            var attachmentResponses = exchangeService.GetAttachments(attachmentIds.ToArray(), null, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent));
```

The process will fail on the GetAttachments call citing a 401 Unauthorized error from the ExchangeWebServiceUrl.

I've looked around but not seen anyone coming across this problem; I have set the permissions in the manifest for my Add-In to ReadWriteMailbox however the issue is still occurring.

I've tried this via running it on the Office Desktop Client and on Chrome using the web browser version of Outlook but get the same issue.

Has anyone came across this before?

EDIT: I should note that I'm able to access the Exchange Web Service if I set the credentials to

```
exchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myUsername", "MyPassword");
```

So it appears to be something with the callback token.

The token decoded returns the following:

> {   "nameid": "641fdcd4-10dd-4441-ac93-41f519e4ad41@venom.local",
>   "ver": "Exchange.Callback.V1",   "appctxsender":
>   "https://localhost:44364/AddinClient@venom.local",   "appctx":
>   "{\"smtp\":\"MyEmail\",\"scope\":\"ParentItemId:AAMkAGY3N2QyYzI2LWRhZTUtNGU3My05MzFmLTYwZGZhZmYyN2QzOQBGAAAAAAAdJ5+qR8pATpmqkddPNb2NBwBgP9yTrGVtSIiRWRnnYVBWAAAAAAEMAABgP9yTrGVtSIiRWRnnYVBWAAA5fvGXAAA=\"}",
>   "iss": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@venom.local",   "aud":
>   "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/outlook.myemailonline.co.uk@venom.local",   "exp": 1546249394,   "nbf": 1546249094 
>   }

The error I'm getting back when trying to call the GetAttachments method is:

> The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized

My EWS token from the callback is:

> "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6InZDcjV1QmxZTmlXZk9udC1iQlFxVXhXYXBaRSJ9.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.boWZO1RJ5FWAxvh0RHek8ebW_j8mbR2ODpSUry0VDeAM6iq2aVYfg_mMUk2kPA4MNCmngJNUv02sAKA82ULlKWevmAo-i2j3AYNjVpmIwBhovaX64SozC0lLSoqC-advp8NsjN0rxV7jn65SD6PP7HE2p-Kc9cDMB9aHpgQY-eUGxkU-dfFvQiAMClPe_eXspW1hUil7prx0wMWUl9fJbsFQgPQMr4dQkYKuCk7DUA3Ih8l_yl1qtySJjrlnrR6EpYlazJQ6sO5V5eb-CMGlcjERyR0UByLwakQpZixnKeu1bs5gs2AYpfOozhFHXvlVCbTxUWlybEWnAbob_bbEaQ"

Comment: Can you validate the token? You can decode using [JWT site](https://jwt.io). Also add the error response from exchange (after removing all personal details) to the question. That way it will be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of the JWT site.  I've made use of that and appended the payload to my question.

Comment: @AndrewFerguson Are you running your add-in service on localhost? Can you also provide EWS token you got?

Comment: Hey there.  I am running it on localhost.  I'll append my EWS token to the original question.

Comment: Curious, the token that you posted does not match what you decoded?  The decoded token should be the result if getCallbackTokenAsync is called with isRest=true. The rest token would not work with EWS.  The EWS token from callback looks correct.  Could you confirm which token you are actually using from the backend?

Comment: Hey there.  Apologies I've been trying a lot of different things to get around this issue so the decoded token is not the one that we are using.  The encoded token I pasted is the one we are using as part of this project.  I'll update the question to have the properly decoded token.

Comment: Could you share a fiddler trace of the EWS request? There may be something wrong with how the headers are being set.

Comment: Hey again.  It looks like we've managed to resolve this issue by using an Office 365 developer account.  So it looks like the issue we are having is because of our email provider.  Thanks for your help with this; I and my team really appreciate it as we've been stuck on this for quite a while.